# cakePHP model associations (retrieving data deeper)

Tags: cakephp, associations, models

I tried to find this everywhere but I cant. Here is my problem:

Lets say I have models associated like this:

1. **Student** (has many Memberships)
2. **Membership** (belongs to Student and TeacherCourse)
3. **TeacherCourse** (belongs to Teacher and Course)
4. **Teacher** (has many TeacherCourses)
5. **Course** (has many TeacherCourses)

When I use `membershipsController` to send all membership to the view, I get only for example `$membership['Membership']['id']` or `$membership['TeacherCourse']['id']` BUT NOT `$membership['TeacherCourse']['Teacher']['id']`...

Which means I get info on Memberships and TeacherCourse because they are directly associated. My question is how can I also get info about Teachers or Courses directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increase the model's recursion level to obtain deeper associations (set `$this->Membership->recursive` to 2 or 3), but in general it's better to use the [`Containable` behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) so you can choose which associations you want to retrieve. For example this would return memberships with associated TeacherCourse and Teacher models:

```
$membership = $this->Membership->find('all', array(
    'contain'=>array(
        'TeacherCourse'=>array(
            'Teacher'=>array()
        ),
    ));
```

See also the full documentation of the Containable behavior at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: You could write that more neatly with: `$membership = $this->Membership->find('all', array('contain'=>array('TeacherCourse.Teacher'));`

Comment: Now I feel stupid I didnt find this myself. Thank you very much for telling me about those two options, ofcourse I decided to go with Containable behaviour.

Comment: One more thing, when i did this, number of mysql queries grew a lot. For every teacher in the membership list it did this: 

"SELECT `Teacher`.`id`, `Teacher`.`first_name`, `Teacher`.`last_name`, `Teacher`.`additional_description`, `Teacher`.`created`, (CONCAT(`Teacher`.`first_name`, ' ' ,`Teacher`.`last_name`)) AS `Teacher__full_name` FROM `glasbena`.`teachers` AS `Teacher` WHERE `Teacher`.`id` = 5"

I sopouse this is normal, because for every membership from the list it has to get a proper teacher?

Comment: Yes. that is the usual behavior of Containable.

Comment: This is known as a "n plus one problem." If the number of queries (and the amount of data returned from the db) becomes a problem there are a few things you can do...

Answer (score 0):

Scratching my head for a few minutes on this one when I realised you need to add the following to the Model first:

`public $actsAs = array('Containable');`

Just adding the contain array in the controller may not return the variables you're looking for in the view without the above.