# Deep association findAll() with CakePHP 2 models

Tags: cakephp-2.0, one-to-many, cakephp-model

I have models `Trip`, `Investment`, and `Person`.  A single trip hasMany investments, and every investment belongsTo one Person.  When I say `$this->Trip->find('all');` I get:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [Trip] => Array (                  
                    [id] => 1
                    [date] => 2012-10-25 13:00:00
                )
            [Investments] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                            [id] => 1
                            [person_id] => 1
                            [investment_type_id] => 2
                            [trip_id] => 1
                            [investment] => 55
                        )
                    [1] => Array (
                            [id] => 2
                            [person_id] => 2
                            [investment_type_id] => 1
                            [trip_id] => 1
                            [investment] => 40
                        )
                )            
        )
)
```

I would like each investment to include the information about the person represented by `person_id` (So their `id`, their `name`, etc).  I've tried all levels of recursion on the `find('all')` lookup with no luck.

Comment: Please post the model code for Investment & Person.

Answer (score 0):

have you defined both ways of association in all models?

eg. Trip hasMany Investments AND Investment belongsTo Trip

Investment belongsTo Person AND Person hasMany Investments
also query should be

```php
$this->Trip->find->("all", array("recursive" => 2));
```

other thing what could be problem is if all necessary models are loaded in your controller

Answer (score 0):

See [cakePHP model associations (retrieving data deeper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515706/cakephp-model-associations-retrieving-data-deeper) for an alternative solution:
Use

```
$this->YourModelname->recursive = 3;
```

before querying.