# CakePHP multiple HABTM associations in containable find

Tags: cakephp, find, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many, contain

I have HABTM associations between two models but can only get find to return one level. I can return several levels with other associations but think I must be missing something with HABTM.

**Controller/SchedulesController.php**

```
$this->Schedule->find('first', array(
  'contain' => array(
    'Association' => array(
      'Schedule'
    )
  )
));
```

**Model/Schedule.php**

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $hasAndBelongToMany = array(
  'Association'
);
```

**Model/Association.php**

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
  'Schedule'
);
```

At the moment I only get...

```
array(
  'Schedule' => array(
     ...
  ),
  'Association' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
      ...
    'AssociationsSchedule' => array(
      ...
    )
  )
)
```

...but I would like Schedule -> Association -> Schedule

Comment: Why do you want the same data twice?

Answer (score -1):

While contain() should work, the other option is to use the `recursive` option before the find like this:

```
$this->Schedule->recursive = 3; //2 might work, but I think you need 3 levels
$this->Schedule->find('first');
```

Its also worth mentioning that a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515931/1473653).